# Pandas groupby dropna=False does not work for apply

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Suppose I have the following dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[None,None,None], 'b':[1,1,2], 'c': [1,1,3], 'd': [1,1,1]})
```

```
df.groupby(['a', 'b', 'c'], dropna=True).d.sum()
=> Series([], Name: d, dtype: int64)
```

```
df.groupby(['a', 'b', 'c'], dropna=False).d.sum()
=> a    b  c
   NaN  1  1    2
        2  3    1
   Name: d, dtype: int64
```

The output is as expected on dropna flag.

Now, I define a custom function to apply.

```
def _is_outlier(s):
    lower_limit = s.mean() - (s.std() * 2)
    upper_limit = s.mean() + (s.std() * 2)
    return ~s.between(lower_limit, upper_limit)
```

```
df.groupby(['a', 'b', 'c'], dropna=False).d.apply(_is_outlier)
=> Series([], Name: d, dtype: bool)
```

```
df.groupby(['a', 'b', 'c'], dropna=True).d.apply(_is_outlier)
=> Series([], Name: d, dtype: bool)
```

Both returns empty series. It looks like dropna does not work as expected for apply function.
Does anybody know a workaround for this issue?

Thanks,

Comment: Which version of pandas are you using?

Comment: You can use drop na  before groupby

Comment: @Simone I'm using  1.3.2

Comment: @Faika Majid Some of the key columns have NaN values and those are valid. Therefore I do not want to drop na before groupby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it is a bug fixed in version 1.3.3. From the [release notes](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.3.3.html):

> Fixed regression in GroupBy.apply() where nan values were dropped even
> with dropna=False [(GH43205)](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/43205)

Can you try to update pandas and check if you still have this issue?

Comment: Thanks Simone. I should upgrade my pandas indeed

Answer (score 0):

Would it solve it to make it a df and then reset the index?

```
pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['a', 'b', 'c'], dropna=False).d.sum()).reset_index()
```